# read file 1 line at a time with variable amount of data on each line

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, getline, chord

I have a question on how to read data from my input .dat file using isstream to be used as a chord implementation
I have inputs of various lengths and type. an example of my input is shown below:

addC 2 #ignore this msg
 
addC 3 #ignore this msg 
addC 9 #ignore this msg
print 9 
insert 2 data0 
insert 9 data1 
insert 3 data2

I would like to capture each input line by line, ignoring any msg behind # key.

What I've done till yet is as follows:

```
if (myfile.is_open()) 
{
    while (getline(myfile, line)) 
    {
        string command;
        string id;
        string input;
        unsigned int hashKey = 0;

        istringstream iss(line);
        getline(iss, command, ' ');
        getline(iss, number, ' ');
        getline(iss, message, '#');
          //other codes
     }
 }
```

however, when i read in my file, it seems that it somehow reads in more then required at times. for example,

//first few commands up till insert 0 is fine
command = insert number = 2 input = data0
INSERTING data0 at: 2
command = insert number = 9 input = data1
command = insert number = 3 input = data2
//program stops here due to some fault in reading i believe

Comment: There is no `insert 0`. And if the arguments to each command are expected in a specific format, then that is exactly what you should be verifying. I.e. `addC` appears to take a single numeric argument. `print` appears to have one as well. `insert` appears to have *two* arguments. If you want to ignore everything past those, terrific, but you should still verify those *first*. Perhaps there is also the possibility that a space isn't the only separator in your file. For example, a `'\t'` separator would easily break what you're currently doing.

Comment: Also, your input data format does not match the input statements.  Your code is expecting a `#` message for the `print 9` line in your text file.  I recommend reading the entire line into a string, then using `istringstream` to extract out by token.